# How to preprocess sequential numbered data before training?

Tags: python, classification, categorical-data, sequential, data-preprocessing

I have a dataset as below:

| Path | Class label |
| --- | --- |
| 4,3 | 0 |
| 4,5,3,7 | 1 |
| 5,3,2,1,8 | 0 |
| 3,4,5 | 1 |

- The 'path' column is a series of sequential numbers with various lengths (>=2).
- The digits are ranging from 1 to 9.
- Each digit can occur multiple times in a 'path' at any position.
- Each digit in the 'path' represents a status in the real-world.
- The aim is to predict the class label based on the 'path' data.

How should I preprocess the 'Path' before using it as training data?

Thanks,

Comment: How many values can the 'path' variable take? Can, for example, a 4 only occur once? If so, you can do something like one hot encoding which results in 9 parameters and one target variable.

Comment: Thanks @Sandertjuhh , Each digit can occur multiple times in a 'path' at any position. One hot encoding may not reflect the sequential aspect.

Comment: Each digit in the 'path' represents a status in the real-world.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Many-to-One architecuture of Recurrent network. Use an LSTM or GRU to implement it.

You pass in your single number of the `path` at each unwrapping of LSTM/GRU the timesteps being then number of numbers the `path` for that sample. You take the output of the last unwrapping and stack up a fully connected layer over it with the last layer being a Dense layer of size equal to the number of classes you want to predict.

[image]

This [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/example-of-many-to-one-lstm/1728) on pytorch forms has implementation details in pytroch.

Comment: Thanks @mujjiga , however, in the blog you posted, there was no need to consider the sequence of the series of 5 vectors. What's more, there will be always 5 vectors for each 'row'. In my case, the sequence of the digits needs to be considered and the length of the path is not consistent (>=2).

Comment: there is no need to have fixed sequence length. This of of a similar problem: Sentiment analysis of a movie review.